# Auto-resize views on iPad with same Aspect ration?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, autoresize, autoresizingmask

I have some views in my app which need to keep always the same aspect `ration`.
For example I have one view which should always have the `width = 2 * height` but when I resizing for `Ipad` the `width` increase too much and the aspect ration is lost.

It is a way to do that with auto-resizing? Or I should calculate manually for every screen?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT!

This is a screenshot with my view controller.

[image]

There are some images. The hover for last 3 items is an `UIView` with background color. Images are `Aspect to Fit` content mode. When the Ipad autoresizing the views, images are keep the aspect fit of Image but the view used for hover is not.

Something like this happened:
[image]

Comment: show us your storyboard and constraints

Comment: You have to calculate manually. You can't give ratio `height:width` from storyboard.

Comment: I just put a screenshot of my view controller and with Ipad auto resizing result